# How to pass a template tag from one template to another in django 2

Tags: django

I  am new to Django, and template tags and HTML and have a template where I use a for loop to fill out bootstrap cards from a database. In the model I has a field Resume_link that has a PDF file. All I want to is have the PDF file displayed in a different template file and not in the card where it is too small to read.  (Since I am in the loop when someone clicks the link, I just want the specific resume connected to that card to be shown in the new template.) So all I think I should need to do is somehow either pass the the index of the loop, or another variable that identifies the correct database entry. But I think I am missing something fundamental and don't understand how to pass the value of a template tag in one template another template. Is there some way to pass a variable along with the url to a view so the variable can be used to make a new template tag in the desired template?

```
 {% for key in myres %}

...fill out other parts of cards and create the below link... 

  <a href="{% url "show_pdf"  %}" style="font-size: 20px">

 {% endfor %}
```

where show_pdf is the view where I want to show the whole PDF file.

and that template show_pdf is

What I would like to do is be able to pass the key.Resume_link.url, or if not that the pk for that database table to the show_pdf template.

The view for show_pdf is

```
def show_pdf(request):
    template = 'show_pdf.html'
    myres=Research.objects.all()
    context = {'myres': myres}
    return render(request,'mainapp/show_pdf.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass the current  pdf `id` in the url and access it.

```
def show_pdf(request, pdf_id):
    template = 'show_pdf.html'
    myres=Research.objects.get(id=pdf_id)
    context = {'myres': myres}
    return render(request,'mainapp/show_pdf.html', context)
```

In you urls.py you must write like this

```
path('show_pdf/?P<int:pdf_id>/', views.show_pdf, name="show_pdf")
```

In HTML write `<a href="{% url "show_pdf" key.id  %}">`

Comment: Thanks, I upvoted, but no reputation. This was very helpful. I ended up with path('show_pdf/<int:pdf_id>/', views.show_pdf, name="show_pdf") and then added another variable to the context, record_to_display = Research.objects.get(pk=pdf_id) and  passed that through the context and it seems to work fine!

Comment: @Photons thanks, there is an option to accept this answer also, it means this answer was very useful in helping you solve the question

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

`<a href="{% url "show_pdf"  %}">`

... you would include a parameter, *e.g.:*

`<a href="{% url "show_pdf" pdf_id  %}">`

The resulting URL would now be formatted as indicated by the corresponding urlconf entry, for instance:

`http://my.web.site/resumes/show_pdf/1343`

(if `pdf_id = 1343` ...)

You must specify as many parameters as the corresponding urlconf entry expects, and you may use either positional or keyword syntax (but not both).

Then, when the user clicks on the link, the View specified in that urlconf will get control, and it will have the specified parameter value (`1343` ...) as one of its arguments.  You'd select the PDF and send it to the template to be properly presented to the user.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I am slowly getting the point that the template language is only for displaying information, not doing programming, once I got the parameter back to the view, and passed the correct record to display it seemed to work.